How can I match timeseries data using PowerQuery in Microsoft Excel?
I have 15 minute interval barologger pressure data and 5 minute interval CT2X pressure data. I would like to match the CT2X data with the barologger data as close as possible. My timeseries runs from 2024-09-02 to 2024-10-17 with the specific time for each ending differently due to taking them out of the field to download the data (11:31 for CT2X and 12:05 for barologger).
I have run the following code with a two minute allowable threshold difference to match, and it works but only provides 1,409 rows and seems to end early on 2024-09-18  but it only provides me with results until 2024-09-18 3:50 for some reason. I don't believe there is a slippage in time as it ran continuously without interruption.
Here is a sample of the data before running the code:

Here is a sample of the data after running the code

Here is the code I used in the Power Query:
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Barologger DateTime (24hr)", type datetime}, {"Barologger LEVEL (cm)", type number}, {"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", type datetime}, {"CT2X Pressure (psi)", type number}}),

#"Added Custom" =Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Match CT2X", (r)=>
let

//generate a list of differences between each of the times
    difs = List.TransformMany(
                #"Changed Type"[#"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)"],
                each {_ -r[#"Barologger DateTime (24hr)"]},
                (a,b)=> Number.Abs(Number.From(b))),

//determine the row numbers with the matching min times, using 2 minutes (2/1440) as the threshold
    pos = if List.Min(difs) < 2/1440
            then List.PositionOf(difs,List.Min(difs))
            else null
    in pos, Int64.Type),

    
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Match CT2X] <> null and [Match CT2X] <> ""),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", "CT2X Pressure (psi)"}),
#"Matching CT2X" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Match CT2X", 
    each Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", "CT2X Pressure (psi)"}){_},type [#"CT2X Date/Time"=datetime, CT2X Pressure=number]}),
#"Expanded Match CT2X" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Matching CT2X", "Match CT2X", {"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", "CT2X Pressure (psi)"}, {"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", "CT2X Pressure (psi)"})

in
#"Expanded Match CT2X"

Here is the link to the dataset that I'm working with:
CT2X and Barologger DataFile

I just posted it to provide context - I would never expect anyone to retype my sample data. Unfortunately, stack overflow won't allow me to attach the excel file so I decided to show with screenshots.

I suggest you edit your question and provide simplified sample input as text, along with desired output

I just updated the question with input as text. I tried to get it as simple as possible but the formatting messes it up. Let me know if you have any further recommendations.

I see you have started a new thread with the exact same question and data. I had mentioned in that thread that I was going to work out a more rapid method, but I will post it here instead.
I used the CombinedBaroCT2X!A:D range for the data source, in the code below.
One could easily use the raw data sheets if that is preferable.
Here is a very fast Power Query method (and a sample of the output) that works on your data.
It works by

Combine the CTX and Baro data into a single pair of columns (adding an ID column so we will be able to tell them apart at the end).
Sort by Date order
Group using the fourth and fifth arguments of Table.Group to return times that are not more than 2 minutes apart.
Check that the grouped tables have two rows with different ID's

Recombine


It does some error checking, but let me know if you run across errors that are not detected.

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Barologger DateTime (24hr)", type datetime}, 
        {"Barologger LEVEL (cm)", type number}, {"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", type datetime}, {"CT2X Pressure (psi)", type number}}),
 
//Split the tables and add ID column
    Barologger = Table.AddColumn(
        Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),0,2)), 
        "ID", each "B",type text),

    CT2X = Table.AddColumn(
                Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type", List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),2)),
                "ID", each "C", type text),

//Interleave and sort by times
    t1 = Table.RenameColumns(Barologger,List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Barologger),{"DateTime","Pressure","ID"}})),
    t2=  Table.RenameColumns(CT2X,List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(CT2X),{"DateTime","Pressure","ID"}})),
    tbl = Table.Combine({t1,t2}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(tbl,{{"DateTime", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each ([DateTime] <> null)),

//Group less than 2 minutes apart
    #"Group by Time" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows",{"DateTime"},{{
        "All", (t)=> if Table.RowCount(t)=1 or List.Count(List.Distinct(t[ID])) = 1  then null
                    else if Table.RowCount(t)>2 then Error.Record("Too many matching rows")
            else let 
                    sortBC = Table.Sort(t,{"ID", Order.Ascending}),
                    Baro = Record.RemoveFields(Record.RenameFields(t{0},{
                            {"DateTime","Barologger DateTime (24hr)"},{"Pressure","Barologger LEVEL (cm)"}}),{"ID"}),
                    CT = Record.RemoveFields(Record.RenameFields(t{1},{
                            {"DateTime","CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)"}, {"Pressure","CT2X Pressure (psi)"}}),{"ID"})
                in 
                    Record.Combine({Baro,CT}),
                type [#"Barologger DateTime (24hr)"=datetime,#"Barologger LEVEL (cm)"=number, 
                        #"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)"= datetime, #"CT2X Pressure (psi)"=number]
    
    }}, GroupKind.Local,(x,y)=>Number.From(Number.Abs(Duration.TotalMinutes(x[DateTime]-y[DateTime]))>2)),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Group by Time",{"DateTime"}),
    #"Removed Nulls" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each [All]<>null),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Nulls", "All", {"Barologger DateTime (24hr)", "Barologger LEVEL (cm)", "CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", "CT2X Pressure (psi)"}, {"Barologger DateTime (24hr)", "Barologger LEVEL (cm)", "CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", "CT2X Pressure (psi)"})
in
    #"Expanded All"

Partial Output

If you should want to start with the RawBarologger and Raw CT2X, you can use the following code:
let

//Read in the raw tables separately into two different queries, named as per Source and Source2
//Process the raw tables
    Source = RawBarologger,
    #"Remove Extra Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"ms","TEMPERATURE"}),
    
    #"Combine Date Time" = 
        Table.TransformColumns(
            Table.CombineColumnsToRecord(#"Remove Extra Columns","Date",{"Date","Time"}),
            {"Date", each [Date] & [Time], type datetime}),

//Add ID Column and Rename Level => Pressure
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Combine Date Time",{{"LEVEL", "Pressure"}}),
    baroID = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns","ID", each "B",type text),

//Process Raw CT2x
    Source2 = #"Raw CT2X Y1",
    #"Remove Extra Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(Source2, {"Date / Time", "Pressure (psi)"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Remove Extra Columns2",{{"Date / Time", "Date"}, {"Pressure (psi)", "Pressure"}}),
    ctID = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "ID", each "C", type text),

//Combine tables and sort
    sorted = Table.Sort(Table.Combine({baroID, ctID}),{"Date", Order.Ascending}),

//group with 2 minute separation max
       #"Group by Time" = Table.Group(sorted,{"Date"},{{
        "All", (t)=> if Table.RowCount(t)=1 or List.Count(List.Distinct(t[ID])) = 1  then null
                    else if Table.RowCount(t)>2 then Error.Record("Too many matching rows")
            else let 
                    sortBC = Table.Sort(t,{"ID", Order.Ascending}),
                    Baro = Record.RemoveFields(Record.RenameFields(t{0},{
                            {"Date","Barologger DateTime (24hr)"},{"Pressure","Barologger LEVEL (cm)"}}),{"ID"}),
                    CT = Record.RemoveFields(Record.RenameFields(t{1},{
                            {"Date","CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)"}, {"Pressure","CT2X Pressure (psi)"}}),{"ID"})
                in 
                    Record.Combine({Baro,CT}),
                type [#"Barologger DateTime (24hr)"=datetime,#"Barologger LEVEL (cm)"=number, 
                        #"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)"= datetime, #"CT2X Pressure (psi)"=number]
    
    }}, GroupKind.Local,(x,y)=>Number.From(Number.Abs(Duration.TotalMinutes(x[Date]-y[Date]))>2)),

//Remove Date column and null tables
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Group by Time",{"Date"}),
    #"Removed Nulls" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns",each [All] <> null),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Nulls", "All", {"Barologger DateTime (24hr)", "Barologger LEVEL (cm)", "CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", "CT2X Pressure (psi)"}, {"Barologger DateTime (24hr)", "Barologger LEVEL (cm)", "CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", "CT2X Pressure (psi)"})
in
    #"Expanded All"


Thank you so much Ron! I appreciate your help this worked fantastically.

I can propose you the formula-based solution:

[G2]=LET(src,A2:D13,maxd,TIME(0,5,0),src1c,CHOOSECOLS(src,1),src3c,CHOOSECOLS(src,3),
  srt,SORT(VSTACK({0,0,0},
    HSTACK(IF(src1c,1),src1c,CHOOSECOLS(src,2)),
    HSTACK(IF(src3c,2),src3c,CHOOSECOLS(src,4)),{0,99999,0}),2),
  srt1c,CHOOSECOLS(srt,1),srt2c,CHOOSECOLS(srt,2),srt3c,CHOOSECOLS(srt,3),
  srt1d,DROP(DROP(srt1c,-1),1),srt2d,DROP(DROP(srt2c,-1),1),
  coln1,IF(MAP(srt1d=1,DROP(srt1c,-2)=2,LAMBDA(x,y,AND(x,y))),srt2d-DROP(srt2c,-2),1),
  coln2,IF(MAP(srt1d=1,DROP(srt1c,2)=2,LAMBDA(x,y,AND(x,y))),DROP(srt2c,2)-srt2d,1),
  coln3,MAP(coln1,coln2,LAMBDA(x,y,MIN(x,y)<maxd)),
  resl3,IF(coln3,IF(coln1<coln2,DROP(srt2c,-2),DROP(srt2c,2)),""),
  FILTER(
    HSTACK(srt2d,DROP(DROP(srt3c,-1),1),resl3,
      IF(coln3,IF(coln1<coln2,DROP(srt3c,-2),DROP(srt3c,2)),"")),
    resl3<>""))

There are two arguments in this formula:

src - the source range.
maxd - the maximal allowable difference between Baro and CT2X timestamps (in both directions).

The solution bases on the sorted array of combined Baro and CT2X measures (1 - Baro, 2 - CT2X) in which closest pairs are sought.


This solution should have the best performance for the large amount of data.

Are you inputting this code in the Advanced Editor of Power Query? When I inputted this code it gave me an "Expression.SyntaxError: Token "," expected." error.

This this the regular Excel formula, just copy it (without "[G2]") and paste onto a worksheet. Excel 2021 or later is required. "G2" is the cell where this formula resides on my screenshot.

I put this solution into the file you provided. The formula provided the result about in a moment (while Power Query stacked my Excel for few minutes).

Your data are timestamped at regular intervals for which the task can be solved much easier, while this solution is able to process data gathered at random moments.

Thank you for your help I got it to work! Appreciate your time and assistance.

Let me know why you prefer Power Query to the formula?

Both are great options. I'm very new to this and figured that Power Query might be easier for large datasets and has a nice user interface.

Power Query is designed to request external data, and interactive usage can be easier to design solutions. Internal data optionally accessible as well. The formulas is the native Excel tool to solve almost all tasks. This way is always faster.

See if this works for you
Checks every row's [Barologger DateTime (24hr)] against every [CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)] and finds the closest [CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)] that has less than a 2 minute difference then returns that [CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)] date/time and [CT2X Pressure (psi)] otherwise null
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Barologger DateTime (24hr)", type datetime}, {"Barologger LEVEL (cm)", type number}, {"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", type datetime}, {"CT2X Pressure (psi)", type number}}),
stored=List.Buffer(#"Changed Type"[#"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)"]),
#"Added Custom" =Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Match CT2X", 
    each let a=[#"Barologger DateTime (24hr)"],
    b= List.Transform(stored, each if Number.Abs(Duration.TotalMinutes(_-a))<2 then Number.Abs(Duration.TotalMinutes(_-a)) else 999999   )
    in if List.Min(b)=999999 then null else stored{List.PositionOf(b,List.Min(b))}, type datetime),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Match CT2X Pressure (psi)", each try #"Added Custom"[#"CT2X Pressure (psi)"]{List.PositionOf(#"Added Custom"[#"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)"],[Match CT2X])} otherwise null)
in #"Added Custom1"



this works by successfully matching the time, however I also need it to include the CT2X pressure readings as well. Do you know how I could include the CT2X pressure to also be included on those matched times?

Edited above answer

Performance leaves much to be desired.

Looking forward to your version then so I can learn. Thanks

You can look at how @RonRosenfeld applied my algorithm in the solution based on Power Query.

I shall study it with interest. Thanks!

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

New formula with INCREDIBLE PERFORMANCE OF LINEAR COMPLEXITY
=LET(baro,A2:B4230,ct2x,C2:D12672,dt,TIME(0,2,0),firs,TAKE(baro,,1),
  si,LAMBDA(i,INDEX(ct2x,i,1)),lamb,LAMBDA(v,p,la,IF(si(v)<p,la(v+1,p,la),v)),
  mapa,MAP(SCAN(2,firs,LAMBDA(a,v,lamb(a,v,lamb))),firs,
    LAMBDA(m,v,LET(va,si(m)-v,vb,v-si(m-1),IF(ABS(MIN(va,vb))<dt,IF(va<vb,m,m-1),1/0)))),
  FILTER(
    HSTACK(baro,INDEX(ct2x,mapa,1),INDEX(ct2x,mapa,2)),
    ISNUMBER(mapa))
)

Since both Baro and CT2X are sorted, this formula uses the linear concurrent loop algorithm to loop through both ranges simultaneously. Recurrent lambda call is used to perform the limited loop.

@RonRosenfeld Let's refactor it with Power Query!

Impressive speed, but I probably won't have time for a while to try it in PQ.

@RonRosenfeld May be later. The opportunity will come again, I guess.
